# How to incorporate a Rails 3.1.x database into a standard ruby app via ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sinatra

I have a Rails 3.1.x app and need to manipulate the data in it's database via another straight ruby app.  Essentially I am just retrieving data from a model in the database.

Obviously it would start off with something like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'mysql2',
  :encoding => 'utf8',
  :database => 'database_name',
  :username => 'username',
  :password => 'password',
  :host => 'hostname'
)
```

But where do I go from here with models already set up?  Do I import the `schema.rb` or models?

Would appreciate a more comprehensive use case example of getting a db used in Rails into a standard ruby script.

Comment: Think I've gotten too long in the tooth for this question and am going to post another one right now with the addition integration scenario instead of adding it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has rake and script/runner. Both can make it easy to access your models and transparently connect to the database.

I've used script/runner when I was retrieving data files from a remote host and needed to insert it into my database underneath the Rails front-end. It worked very nicely.

Read through some of these Stack Overflow questions for more info:

- [script/runner](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ruby-on-rails]++runner&submit=search)
- [rake tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ruby-on-rails]+[rake]+runner)

Comment: Yes, it seems as though integration at some level under the Rails app itself may make sense, especially since one of the scripts will ultimately be required for a model I think (not sure how the dynamics or interrelationships may work yet in this regard with pulling in a class to use in a model).  The key here is db read access in order to pull data series out of the db to pass through the script.

Comment: script/runner is equivalent to running Rails without the HTTP server and presentation stuff. For ActiveRecord/ActiveSupport stuff it was very nice.

Comment: Seems like just running rake tasks may be the right approach here.  I've already got a number of them set up, but they're working directly with models.  I'll add a little more information about my Rails app in the main question as I think we're moving along the right path now.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the model files. The `schema.rb` is only relevant if you'll be using migrations and it's probably a bad idea to split those across two different applications. Use your Rails app as your master and your new Ruby app as a dependent application.

Just be sure that if your models have any dependencies those are included as well.

In some instances it might be easier to create another directory in your Rails repository for hosting this other Ruby application if they are sufficiently tied together.

Comment: This other app is purely a testing platform for some concepts outside of the core Rails app.  It will never insert data into the database.  Could you recommend a more specific approach of how to extract data? I would be willing to insert the scripts at some level into the Rails app (was considering /lib since ultimately a couple of these scripts will be called from cron rake tasks).  I just need to understand what a solid approach may be in this scenario that would allow flexibility and full db read access.

Comment: After thinking more about what you've said and the others, I'm thinking that perhaps the best approach may be to rather integrate these scripts into the Rails app under /lib or such... but I'm not clear of how to best accomplish this.  Edited the above question to give some more clarity in my scenario and would appreciate some more input if you have any thoughts there.

Comment: The `script/runner` approach isn't a bad idea as long as the tasks in question aren't extraordinarily complicated. For those you might want to look at [Delayed Job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or something like that.

Comment: Well, right now I have just tried to add a task that does a `bundle exec lib/script.rb`.  Unfortunately, when I have a require at the top of `script.rb` for `lib/another_script.rb` it's not finding it's path.  I'm missing some nuts and bolts understanding of what really is going on or how i should structure rake tasks it appears.  I pushed this over to here for further discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304121/how-to-integrate-previously-external-ruby-scripts-into-a-rails-app-and-call-them

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before, 1 x Sinatra app and 5 x rails apps.

However my approach requires git and git submodule.

Move the /models dir into a new project with its own repo.

Require that project as a submodule (mapped to /models) within each app which wants to use it.
This then means that you only ever need to edit one version of the models to update all applications which use them.

GitHub has a pretty good guide on submodule:
http://help.github.com/submodules/